# Arcgis maps SDK 4.27 with Asp.Net Core 3.1 MVC does not read require tag constructors

Tags: asp.net-core, arcgis-js-api

The below code works when launched when created as an html page in notepad. However, once I try to deploy as part of a Asp.net Core project it will not display unless i change the Arcgis SDK down to 4.15. Anything greater than SDK 4.16 will not work. Can't find any reason for this on the web. Below code returns error: Uncaught TypeError: MapView is not a constructor.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.27/esri/themes/light/main.css" />
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.27/"></script>


<style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<script>
        
    require(["esri/WebMap", "esri/views/MapView", "esri/widgets/Editor"], (
        WebMap,
        MapView,
        Editor
    ) => {
        // Create a map from the referenced webmap item id
        const webmap = new WebMap({
            portalItem: {
                id: "4793230052ed498ebf1c7bed9966bd35"
            }
        });

        const view = new MapView({
            container: "viewDiv",
            map: webmap
        });

        view.when(() => {
            const editor = new Editor({
                view: view
            });

            // Add the widget to the view
            view.ui.add(editor, "top-right");
        });
    });
    
</script>

<div id="viewDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a hunch that this had something to with my page/view references conflicting js. By doing the following sdk 4.27 is no working.

The way I got around was to comment out this section of the shared Asp.net Core App _layout.cshtml view

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

As it appears to conflict with any arcgis sdk of higher than 4.15

I also had to comment out the following in my view:

```
section Scripts {
        @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    }
```